# Using a template file for a specific custom URL

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

I was trying to use a custom URL to load a page template for `single-events.php` without rewriting the default URL format. I am using filter `template_include` to load the template like this:

```
add_filter('template_include','include_template_for_single_event',99);
function include_template_for_single_event($template)
{
    //check_for_single_event() will check if the current url = custom url
    if( check_for_single_event() ){
        $new_template = locate_template(array('single-events.php','single.php'));
        if($new_template)$template = $new_template;
    }     
   return $template;
}
```

The issue with this is that the contents of the single cpt within the loop is not loading which means there is no data for the single cpt such as `get_the_ID()`, `have_posts()` etc

### Edit:

I do have a default link for a single post of a custom post type

```
example.com/nepal/events/visit-year-2020
```

Now, I want to load this same page template with URL

```
example.com/nepal/events/visit-year-2020/2020-01-10.
```

P.S. client still want the default URL and this new URL with every date available appended to the end.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I do have a default link for a single post of a custom post type `example.com/nepal/events/visit-year-2020` Now, I want to load this same page template with URL `example.com/nepal/events/visit-year-2020/2020-01-10`. P.S. client still want the default URL and this new URL with every date available appended to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `nepal` is (text prefix only or maybe taxonomy term), but it is not the most important thing, you will correct it if necessary. Rewrite rule like this should resolve the case.

```
add_action( 'init', 'se356109_events_custom_rule' );
function se356109_events_custom_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'nepal/events/(.+?)/([0-9\-]+)(:?/page/?([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?events=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

If you need to use URL date (in your example "*2020-01-10*") somewhere, you need to add a new query variable (with any name, e.g. `custom_dt`) and modify rewrite rule.

```
add_action( 'init',       'se356109_events_custom_rule' );
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'se356109_query_vars' );

function se356109_query_vars( $vars )
{
    $vars[] = 'custom_dt';
    return $vars;
}

function se356109_events_custom_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'nepal/events/(.+?)/([0-9\-]+)(:?/page/?([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?events=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[3]&custom_dt=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

And that's how you read the value of this new variable:

```
$dt = get_query_var('custom_dt', false);
```

Comment: I am on localhost right now and this is not working. maybe coz the url is  `localhost/tour/nepal/events/..` rather than `example.com/nepal/events..` ?

Comment: Permalinks will need to be refreshed (you can do this from your admin under Settings > Permalinks -> Save) before the rewrite changes will take effect. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Still not working. My localhost link to the page is: `http://localhost/tour/nepal/events/visit-year-2020/2020-01-13`. Both `('nepal/events/(.+?)/([0-9\-]+)` and `('tour/nepal/events/(.+?)/([0-9\-]+)` is not working.

Comment: I am using just `'tour/nepal/events/(.+?)/([0-9\-]+)(:?/page/?([0-9]+))?/?$'`. No luck

Comment: `events` is custom post type, and what is `tour` and `nepal`? Can you copy the results of this code and paste them, e.g. in `https://pastebin.com/`?
`add_action( 'wp_footer', 'se_footer_rewrite_dump', 80 );
function se_footer_rewrite_dump() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    echo '<pre>RULES-TOP <br>'.print_r($wp_rewrite->extra_rules_top, true);
    echo '<br><br>PERMASTRUCTS<br>'.print_r($wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs, true).'</pre>';
}`

Comment: URL Structure of a single event: ```http://localhost/pht/zante/events/tidal-boat-party/```
Where `pht` is local project folder name (previously tours), `zante` is a location like Nepal, `events` is a custom post type. 
Rewrite dump you requested: ```https://pastebin.com/5VyiVxQ5```

Comment: The `"^([^/]+)/events/(.+)"` rule is earlier in the rewrites table than the one that supports dates, and that is the cause of the problem. Change the priority (the default is 10) so that the `se356109_events_custom_rule` function performs earlier and reverse the order of these two rules: `add_action( 'init', 'se356109_events_custom_rule', 8 );`.

Comment: Because the text before `events/` it is not always `nepal`, you should change the beginning of the rule to `'^(?:([^/]+))/events/(.+?)/([0-9\-]+)...`. Another option is `'^([^/]+)/events/(.+?)/([0-9\-]+)...` and replacing `$matches[1]` to `$matches[2]`, `$matches[2]` to `$matches[3]` and so on.

Comment: I guess I know why this was not working. `http://localhost/pht/index.php?events=tidal-boat-party` this was not directed to the event because client had a permalink manager plugin installed to change the default permalink `http://localhost/pht/events/zante-events-tidal-boat-party`. Now I don't think it will work with the custom permalink. Also, if I change the permalink to default and implement our rule, it will redirect to the original event page, not the one with dates in the end

Comment: So, I matched our rule according to the original slug (leaving the permalink structure changed by the client as it is), and it did redirect me to the original event page, However, the date, at the end, is gone. the URL should contain the `/2020-01-22`at the end as well.

Comment: Any suggestions?